# I am trying to connect to mysql using python but I got Error

Tags: python, mysql, database, compiler-errors, pycharm

I tried to connect to database Mysql by using python on Pycharm but I got Error, 
I tried mysql.connector, MySQLdb,pymysql but it's failed.
I am using Mac Mojave version 10.14, MAMP server, pycham.

This is the code I used:

```html
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    passwd="root",
    db="newm",
    host="localhost",
    user="root"
    )

print(mydb)
```

and I got this Error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EkCQ.png)

Comment: check your mysql access credentials. have u connect with the same credentials using CLI ?. If mysqldb was freshly installed, you can use it without password like sending empty string `''`,